# NonlinearModelFit : How to get the values of the individual parameters from the matrix "ParameterTable"

Tags: fitting, list-manipulation, nonlinear, parameters

I just made a NonlinearModelFit :

```
 nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {Piecewise[{{-((
   n0 r - (lambda n0 R)/(
    lambda - lambda phiL + phiL R Coth[R]))/(-r + R)), r < 0}, {(
  lambda n0 R Csch[R/lambda] Sinh[(-r + R)/
    lambda])/((-r + R) (lambda - lambda phiL + phiL R Coth[R])), 
  r > 0}}], 0 < lambda < 300 && 300 < R < 375 && 0 < phiL < 1}, {lambda, R, phiL}, r]
```

And read the parameters that resulted :

```
  nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

If I copy past it it's something like that :

> Estimate
>       
>       
>        Standard Error
>       
>       
>        t‐Statistic
>       
>       
>        P‐Value
>       
>      
>      
>       
>        lambda
>       
>       
>        135.68187533976533
>       
>       
>        20.981462255825214
>       
>       
>        6.4667502047954315
>       
>       
>        0.007502993516948019
>       
>      
>      
>       
>        R
>       
>       
>        300.0000504177876
>       
>       
>        67.82635272927216
>       
>       
>        4.423060334900111
>       
>       
>        0.021460812816808023
>       
>      
>      
>       
>        phiL
>       
>       
>        0.04527481766196899
>       
>       
>        0.01810272462912522
>       
>       
>        2.5009946618271464
>       
>       
>        0.08762977813441623
>       
>      
>     
>     TagBox[GridBox[List[List["\"\"", "\"Estimate\"", "\"Standard Error\"", "\"t-Statistic\"", "\"P-Value\""], List["lambda", "135.68187533976533`", "20.981462255825214`", "6.4667502047954315`", "0.007502993516948019`"], List["R", "300.0000504177876`", "67.82635272927216`", "4.423060334900111`", "0.021460812816808023`"], List["phiL", "0.04527481766196899`", "0.01810272462912522`", "2.5009946618271464`", "0.08762977813441623`"]], Rule[AutoDelete, False], Rule[GridBoxAlignment, List[Rule["Columns", List[List[Left]]], Rule["Rows", List[List[Automatic]]]]], Rule[GridBoxDividers, List[Rule["ColumnsIndexed", List[Rule[2, GrayLevel[0.7`]]]], Rule["RowsIndexed", List[Rule[2, GrayLevel[0.7`]]]]]], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, List[Rule["Columns", List[List[Automatic]]], Rule["Rows", List[List[Automatic]]]]], Rule[GridBoxSpacings, List[Rule["ColumnsIndexed", List[Rule[2, 1]]], Rule["RowsIndexed", List[Rule[2, 0.75`]]]]]], "Grid"]

The image is : 
[image]

But I'd like to get the values separately, and writing something like

```
       nlm["ParameterTable"][[2]][[2]]
```

doesn't work !

So how could I extract so individual values of the parameters and not just having the table please ?

Comment: Please have a look at `nlm["Properties"]` and "BestFitParameters".

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the possible keys to give to the fit result?

```
nlm["ParameterTableEntries"]
```

would probably do.